# Probability - coins

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need to solve the following problem:

We do $n$ independent throws with a leveled coin. I have to  calculate the probability to get exactly $n-1$ faces in two different cases:

1) We've got at least $n-2$ faces

2) In the first $n-2$ throws we've got faces

---

I've managed to do the second case. I've done it with the binomial distribution. I've defined:

$p=0.5$ (the probability to get a face)

$X = (n-2,p)$ (number o faces in the first $n-2$ throws)

$Y = (2,p)$ (number of faces in the last two throws)

$A =$ to get exactly $n-1$ faces

And I've calculated $P(A)=P(X=n-2)P(Y=1)=2^{1-n}$

But **I don't know how to do case 1).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1),

- the probability of exactly $n-2$ heads is ${n \choose n-2}2^{-n} =\frac{n(n-1)}2 2^{-n}$
- the probability of exactly $n-1$ heads is ${n \choose n-1}2^{-n} = n 2^{-n}$
- the probability of exactly $n$ heads is ${n \choose n}2^{-n} = 2^{-n}$

so the probability of at least $n-2$ heads is the sum of those which is $\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}2^{-n}$

and the conditional probability of exactly $n-1$ heads given at least $n-2$ heads is $$\dfrac{n 2^{-n}}{\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}2^{-n}} = \frac{2n}{n^2+n+2}$$

For (2), you can change the question to the probability of getting exactly $1$ head in the last $2$, which is ${2 \choose 1}2^{-2}=\frac12$